# Reformatting ['0','0 1 ','0 1 2','0 1 2 3'] to ['0',['0','1'],...]

Tags: python

I have a list as `UEID = ['0','0 1 ','0 1 2','0 1 2 3']` need an output as `['0',['0','1'],...]`, i.e. `UEID[1][1]` should print `1`

My code:

```
for x in UEID:
    if " " in UEID[x]:
        ueid_list = [int(j) for j in UEID[x]]
        print ueid_list
```

This is showing an error as:

```
TypeError: list indices must be in integer, not str
```

Comment: If Amits answer solved your matter than accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

try below code

```
UEID = ['0','0 1 ','0 1 2','0 1 2 3']
print [x.split() if len(x)>1 else x for x in UEID]
```